# Farseer - Apply Impulse

Tags: xna, c#, physics, silverlight, farseer-physics-engine

I'm new to Farseer and have a simple question. The demos I went through didn't seem to demonstrate what I want. I would like to apply an impulse (not force) to an object at a specific position on that object. How would I go about doing this in code? (I've created the objects already). I'll be using XNA and SL, but I guess the code for this method would be the same. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't used it, but a quick google search turned up [this thread](http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=239605).

Here is a summary:

> When you apply a impulse or force using `ApplyLinearImpulse` or
> `ApplyForce` respectively, you can specify a point indicating where to
> apply the impulse or force on the target.
>
> To apply angular velocity, use `ApplyAngularImpulse`.
>
> The **moment of inertia** can be considered as an object's resistance
> to changes in its rotation; the greater the moment of inertia is, the
> harder it is to make it rotate.
>
> **Torque** is like a force that rotate an object on an axis, it can be thought of as a twist.
>
> Consider a game of pool / billiards using:
>
> `ApplyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0f, 100f), new Vector2(0,0));`
>
> The first parameter is the direction and magnitude of the impulse. Since the shape is a
> circle, the second parameter will apply torque. Specifically, it is
> the local coordinates on the circle where you apply the impulse. Thus,
> the first parameter should contain the angle the cue has to the center
> of the circle. The second parameter should be the point of impact on
> the ball.The first parameter is both

It makes sense since all physics engines, in my experience, give you the ability to apply impulses and/or forces. So look for the ApplyLinearImpulse/ApplyAngularImpulse functions. They enable you to specify points where you apply the impulse.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that when I searched, but looks like what I need :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the Body.ApplyLinearImpulse, or you can directly set the Body.LinearVelocity.